# Error al declarar una variable en typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hola tengo el siguiente error en TypeScript, al declarar una variable, el problema es que solo tengo esa variable en todo el archivo, y no importa cual sea el tipo de variable me arroja el mismo error y al compilar a JavaScript me arroja error en el navegador.

Mi código:

```
let superman: boolean = false;
```

Y genera el siguiente error:

> [ts] Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'superman'.

Ya actualice mi versión de TypeScript y sigue igual el asunto.

¿Sera que debo configurar Visual studio code? o algún plugin causa ese fallo.

Saludos y ojala me puedan ayudar. Gracias

Comment: ¿Sólo tienes una línea en el archivo? Ese error aparece por tener al menos dos definiciones de `superman` en el mismo *scope*.

Comment: Así es solo tengo declarada esa variable, no tengo ni una sola línea de código más, ahí radica mi problema no se porque me arroja ese error

Comment: ¿Y cómo has lamado al fichero `.ts`?¿Que sale en el fichero javascript? Dinos alguna pista más para que no tengamos que usar una bola de cristal.

Comment: Hola ya lo resolvi muchas gracias, no se porque pero el visual studio code, al instalarle el nuevo paquete de idiomas para traducirlo al español me creo un conflicto en todos los lenguajes, solo le di restaurar y listo. Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Desde chrome ejecuta por consolta

```
console.log(superman);
```

En caso que te devuelva un valor distinto a **undefined**
Debes cambiar de nombre la variable o moverla de modulo.

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

Comment: aun sigue arrojando el mismo error. Saludos

Comment: Sin ejecutar tu linea, corres la app, y ejectas console.log(superman); te devuelve algun resultado?

Comment: Hola ya lo resolvi muchas gracias, no se porque pero el visual studio code, al instalarle el nuevo paquete de idiomas para traducirlo al español me creo un conflicto en todos los lenguajes, solo le di restaurar y listo. Gracias por la ayuda